# Poor Leaflet.js Performance in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, leaflet, mapbox

I am trying to build a map-based web app using mapbox and leaflet.js.

I am loading around 300 markers into a featureLayer from a geoJSON file. This seems to work beautifully in every browser except internet explorer, which freezes for a good 10 seconds or so every time markers are loaded or filtered using featureLayer.setFilter. I have uploaded a demo of this [here](http://www.archiventure.co.uk/mapdemo/maptest.html).

Locking at the IE performance analysis the culprit seems to be the 'addDoubleTapListener'. This seems to be a known issue (https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/4357), and the solutions suggest rolling back to leaflet 0.7.5, or using the 0.7.7.1 branch (which has a fix that reverts touch detection). I have tried both, and neither seem to have any effect on the issue. Upgrading to the leaflet 1.0.0-beta is also suggested, but this doesn't seem to be compatible with the current mapbox...

Any help with overcoming this issue would be much appreciated.

Comment: I've loaded a couple thousand markers in IE (9+) and haven't noticed this problem, but I don't really use `setFilter`. I usually add markers gradually in chunks via AJAX. Does it improve at all if instead of `L.geoJson(data)` you add chunks of features at a time via `geoJsonLayer.addData()` ? Also,  can you please make a fiddle with your sample code so we can test and profile?

Comment: I have the same performance issue in the Edge.

Answer (score 2):

Ok the solution I found was to remove the following lines from leaflet-src.js 0.7.7.1:

```
if (L.Browser.touch && (type === 'dblclick') && this.addDoubleTapListener) {
    this.addDoubleTapListener(obj, handler, id);
}
```

IE now loads the markers lightning fast and all of the functions appear to still be working in all the devices I tried. Not an ideal solution, but will serve as a stop-gap solution until Mapbox supports Leaflet 1.0.0.

Comment: interesting.. haven't tested on a windows touch device though I use leaflet with iOS and android devices. what does double tap do, anyway? zoom in? useless. What hardware were you testing IE on and did it support touch? maybe this is why i haven't seen it, will try later if i can secure a windows touch device

Comment: Perfect solution!